# How to get content-Element from XML rss feed using PHP?

Tags: php, xml

how can I get the content-Element from XML? Other solutions on stackoverflow could not help me, I'm doing something wrong.. This is how I read the feed:

```
<?php
            $content = file_get_contents('some feed url');
            $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);

            foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
                $chi = $entry->children('content', true)->encoded;
            }
?>
```

XML: https://pastebin.com/79dgx8cU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
$x = new SimpleXmlElement($str);
$x->registerXPathNamespace('content', 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/');

$result = $x->xpath('//channel/item/content:encoded');
if(count($result) > 0) {
    foreach($result as $element) {
        echo (string)$element . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should loop through this `$result` and cast into string like i did for 0th element.